# Multipart/form - Create a string from checkboxes and send to db

Tags: java, forms, jsp, checkbox, multipart

I have a multipart/form-data form that contains a file upload section and other fields such as checkboxes. I would like to create a string based on the information from checkboxes, delimitered with ";" in order to send it to the database.

My UploadServlet looks like this:

```
try {
        // parses the request's content to extract file data
        List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

        // iterates over form's fields
        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
            // processes only fields that are not form fields
            if (!item.isFormField()) {

                                    //doSomething 

                String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                File storeFile = new File(filePath);    

                // saves the file on disk
                item.write(storeFile);


            }
            else
            {

            // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                // Do anotherThing


               // Can I create a string from the checkbox inputs here?

            }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect multiple fields with the same name yourself. Assuming that the input field name of those checkboxes is `checkboxName`, here's a kickoff example:

```
List<String> checkboxValues = new ArrayList<String>(); 

// ... while looping over all items.

String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
String fieldvalue = item.getString();

if ("checkboxName".equals(fieldname)) {
    checkboxValues.add(fieldvalue);
}

// ... after looping over all items.

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (String checkboxValue : checkboxValues) {
    if (builder.length() > 0) builder.append(";");
    builder.append(checkboxValue);
}

String semicolonSeparatedCheckboxValues = builder.toString();
// Save in DB. By the way, why not just using a separate table with a FK?
// Storing multiple values delimited in a single DB column is a bad practice.
```

Answer (score 0):

For Apache Commons FileUpload, there will always be one item for every HTML element in the multipart form that you submitted.

So if you have multiple checkboxes with the same name, you will get multiple items with the same field names. In other words, for many checkboxes, you will find many items with the same field name, but with different value.

Comment: I cannot use request.getParameter() because I am using Apache Common File Upload API (due to the multipart/form stuff). Is there any other option?